# c3.js: Remove categories from x-axis

Tags: c3.js

I've spent a lot of time with c3's documentation and examples, but have not been able to find a a way to unload or hide a category from a chart using API functions. Removing lines or bars is easy, but removing x-axis categories is proving more challenging. Here is a streamlined version of my chart.

```
    var genderChart = c3.generate({
    bindto: '#chart-gender',
    data: {
        json: [
          {
            Disease:"Mumps",
            "Female":231,
            "Male":198
          },
            Disease:"Tuberculosis",
            "Female":18,
            "Male":197
          }
        ],

        type: 'bar',
        keys: {
            x: "Disease",
            value: ["Female","Male"]
        },
        selection: {
            enabled: true,
            grouped: true
        },
    },

    axis: {
        x: {
            type: 'category',
        }        
    },
});
```

I would like to dynamically show and hide (load and unload) diseases. For instance, I would like to be able to toggle Tuberculosis on and off. My actual chart has a number of other diseases. If I structured the data such that the diseases were bars and gender was on the x-axis, this would be easy. However, that is not comparison I wish to show with this chart. Is this possible with c3? How do I select all of the values with a given x value (disease) and then unload those data points? I appreciate any insight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would build up the json data object and then re-render the chart.

Here's an example:

```
var data = [{
    Disease: "Mumps",
    Female: 231,
    Male: 198
}, {
    Disease: "Tuberculosis",
    Female: 18,
    Male: 197
}];

$("button").click(function () {
    Render();
});

Render()

function Render() {

    var selectedData = [];
    if ($("#mumps").prop("checked")) selectedData.push(data[0]);
    if ($("#tb").prop("checked")) selectedData.push(data[1]);

    var genderChart = c3.generate({
        data: {
            json: selectedData,

            type: 'bar',
            keys: {
                x: "Disease",
                value: ["Female", "Male"]
            },
            selection: {
                enabled: true,
                grouped: true
            },
        },

        axis: {
            x: {
                type: 'category',
            }
        },
    });
}
```

Here's the code in a fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/ot19Lyt8/14/

Comment: Thank you for the response. The method definitely works. I need to be careful with the size of the function however. It can pretty heavy depending on the chart that is getting re-rendered.